# use asyncio update some data timely and present via aiohttp?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am in trying to write a snippet to study Python asyncio. The basic idea is:

1. use a "simple" web server (aiohttp) to present some data to user
2. the data return to user will change promptly

here is the code:

```
import asyncio
import random
from aiohttp import web

userfeed = [] # the data suppose to return to the user via web browsers 

async def data_updater():  #to simulate data change promptly
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        userfeed = [x for x in range(random.randint(1, 20))]
        print('user date updated: ', userfeed)


async def web_handle(request):
    text = str(userfeed)
    #print('in handler:', text)  # why text is empty?
    return web.Response(text=text)

async def init(loop):
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/', web_handle)
    srv = await loop.create_server(app.make_handler(), '127.0.0.1', 8000)
    print('Server started @ http://127.0.0.1:8000...')
    return srv

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(data_updater())  
asyncio.ensure_future(init(loop))
loop.run_forever()
```

the problem is, the code is running (python 3.5), but the `userfeed` is always empty in browsers and also in `web_handler()` :-(

1. why `userfeed` is not been updated?
2. regarding this `timely date update` function, because the update mechanism might be more complex later say async IO wait may be involved, is there a better way instead of using `while True: await asyncio.sleep(3)` in `data_updater()` to get "more roughly precise" timer?

Comment: You want to push notifications to the user browsing your page (without any action from him) ? If so, you should take a look to the *websocket* technology, it is implemented in `aiohttp` in a pretty straightforward way (there is [examples](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/examples/web_ws.py) in the source code). Otherwise you should use your [`app` object](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#id3) (which provide a `dict` interface) to pass the `userfeed` variable between functions and avoid to make it global.

Comment: @mgc，thanks for replying. I do not want the data automatically flushing in user's browser, just a client pull model could enough - each time one open the URL via browser or tool like wget , latest data can present. The confuse here is, why the global variable not been updated(inside of `web_handler()` print shows it is always [], but `data _updater()` do print it is changed)? async def is different than normal def it will caching context somehow?

Comment: See my answer for an example, as using global variable in this context is explicitly  discouraged by the [documentation](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web.html#data-sharing-aka-no-singletons-please). But if you really need to make it working using a global `userfeed`, just add `global userfeed` in both `data_updated` and `web_handle` functions and it should works (this way the function know that `userfeed` refers to a variable located in global scope, in your example each function had its own local `userfeed`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you forget the statement `global userfeed` in both `data_updater` and `web_handle` functions. So, according to [how python resolves scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/5050917), in `web_handle` it was referring to the global variable you defined and in `data_updater` to a local one, created by the statement `userfeed = [x for x ...`. Using global variables in this context is explicitly [discouraged](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web.html#data-sharing-aka-no-singletons-please) so there is an example using the `dict` interface of the `aiohttp.web.Application` object to safely refer to your variable between the functions.

```
import asyncio
import random
from aiohttp import web


async def data_updater(app):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        app["userfeed"] = [x for x in range(random.randint(1, 20))]

async def web_handle(request):
    userfeed = request.app["userfeed"]
    return web.Response(text=str(userfeed))

async def init(loop, port=8000):
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/', web_handle)
    handler = app.make_handler()
    srv = await loop.create_server(
        handler, '127.0.0.1', port=port)
    return srv, app, handler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    srv, app, handler = loop.run_until_complete(init(loop, 8000))
    app['userfeed'] = []
    asyncio.ensure_future(data_updater(app))
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        srv.close()
        loop.run_until_complete(srv.wait_closed())
        loop.run_until_complete(app.shutdown())
        loop.run_until_complete(handler.finish_connections(60.0))
        loop.run_until_complete(app.cleanup())
    loop.close()
```

When you refresh the page on `127.0.0.1:8000` you should have some new random numbers as they are updated every 3 seconds server-side (you can put back the `print` statement in `data_updater` to verify it).

Comment: seems I made a stupid abc mistake:( many thanks for your detailed explanation, really appreciated

Comment: Glad it helped!